# CSS Margin-Top with Percentage -- Cross Browser Issue

Tags: css

I'm working on an overlay in CSS and ran into a cross browser issue. The overlay height should be 80% of the viewport and be centered vertically. (80% height on the element, -40% top margin, 50% from top positioned absolutely).

The fiddle below works in Chrome but not in Firefox.. the issue seems to be the percentage for margin-top. Make sure to resize your browser to see the full effect.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/DEn6r/1/

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using percentages for both `top` and `margin-top`, you can combine them, and simply use `top: 10%`.

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/DEn6r/3/

Also, if you'd like to drop the negative left margin, you can use this trick to center the div horizontally:

```
#inside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;  // set left and right to 0
  margin: 0 auto; // set left and right margins to auto
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Dang! So simple. Thanks jackwanders!

Comment: I do find the Firefox implementation of @Adam Storr's original CSS interesting; curious to know what it's measuring 40% of

Comment: The 40% is half of the height (80%) which works with the `top: 50%` to center it in the view. This works with positioning elements with specific pixel dimensions... but obviously not with percentages.

Comment: Right, I get that's how it *should* work. But obviously, Firefox doesn't play nice. It's value for "40%" is different than Chrome's